# Capture progressbar value onMouseClick

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have progress bar, when I click on progressbar it should get the value(of progressbar where mouse is clicked) 
here is the XAML of progressbar

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="seekBar" Height="21" Margin="30,36,43,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ValueChanged="seekBar_ValueChanged" BorderBrush="#FF9B99C3" BorderThickness="2">
    <ProgressBar.Foreground>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF505285" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF858AF0" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ProgressBar.Foreground>
    <ProgressBar.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF0F0F0F" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF326ED6" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFD1DBEE" Offset="0.491"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ProgressBar.Background>
    <ProgressBar.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.15"/>
    </ProgressBar.Effect>
</ProgressBar>
```

When the value is changed it calls the function C# code

```
private void seekBar_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.seekBar.Value = //what should i do here??
    //how to get the value of progressbar(where mouse is clicked)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
private void seekBar_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    double MousePosition = e.GetPosition(seekBar).X;
    this.seekBar.Value = SetProgressBarValue(MousePosition);
}

private double SetProgressBarValue(double MousePosition)
{
    double ratio = MousePosition/seekBar.ActualWidth;
    double ProgressBarValue = ratio*seekBar.Maximum;
    return ProgressBarValue;
}
```

Codes adapted from following reference (see codes posted at the end of discussion) : http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/722714-allowing-user-click-progressbar